# How to save a 3d Plotly graph to html from a Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, plotly

I'm looking for a way to export a Jupyter notebook, which contains 3D Plotly charts (just like [this one in the documentation](https://plot.ly/python/3d-surface-plots/)), to html, without losing the visualizations.

It would also be OK if there was a way to just save the 3D charts offline in a separate html file, but obviously together with the rest of the notebook would be better.

Does anyone know how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

For Interactive HTML Export, please refer to [this link](https://plotly.com/python/interactive-html-export/?_gl=1*1wb6539*_ga*MTkyNzQ3MzAwMi4xNjY0NzU2Mzc5*_ga_6G7EE0JNSC*MTY2NDc5MTQ4NS4zLjEuMTY2NDc5MTQ5My4wLjAuMA..#:%7E:text=Interactive%20HTML%20Export%20in%20Python).

```
import plotly.express as px
fig =px.scatter(x=range(10), y=range(10))
fig.write_html("path/to/file.html")
```